# Can I edit a post as to delete a edited portion of it for good?

Tags: support

say I post something I realize afterward is embarrasing and/or inconvenient (say a password, a friend's phone number, ecc.).

May I ask to delete it, in strong sense to remove from the system? How?

If not, why?

Comment: You can always delete your posts, right?  Or you mean a permanent delete from SO's db's too?

Comment: I mean a "a permanent delete from SO's db's"

Comment: -1? why? It seems to a reasonable question.

Comment: The downvotes may be due to it being a duplicate, hence lack of research.

Comment: Also don't forget to change you password!

Answer (score 3):

> say I post something I realize afterward is embarrasing and/or inconvenient (say a password, a friend's phone number, ecc.).

So, you want these edited out - and not be available in any revision of the post, if I understand correctly.

First, edit out the problematic bits (password, phone number, any other sensitive bits).

Then flag the post and explain what the issue is - moderators have tools to redact revisions - so passwords and other sensitive information will not longer be in any revision.

---

If you are talking about deleting a complete post - that's somewhat different (I doubt a whole post will contain such sensitive information - possibly just part of it - and in that case, see above).

You can delete your own question if it has zero answers or one answer without any upvotes, similarly you can just delete any of your answers.

Again, you can flag such a post for deletion - explain why it needs to be deleted. Note that the issue needs to be more than just "I am embarrassed about what I posted" for moderators to take any steps. Point being - the issue you posted may be of help to others - and when posting on the sites - you have licensed them as cc-by-sa (see the footer) to Stack Overflow, meaning - we have the right to keep them around.

Comment: I am not talking about (hard) deleting a complete post, but just say to (hard) delete a line of a cut&paste piece of code within a post, with happens to show sensitive info. I know about cc-by-sa, does it covers typos?

Comment: That's what redacting is for.

Comment: Let me understand: The only way to (hard?) delete is to ask a moderator to 'redact'  (a revision of mine of) my post? (Do we have a definition of 'redact'?) Thks

Comment: If you want a *part* of a post to be gone, forever, yes, you need to ask a moderator to redact that part, from all revisions. We do not hard delete whole posts.

Comment: Ok, I understand. To round it off, to redact by a moderator ('from all revisions') does not imply that that piece of info is deleted from servers and databases, does it?